If $G$ is a locally compact topological group, $H\triangleleft G$ with $H$ and $G/H$ compactly generated, then so is $G$.
I've been studying the next theorem stated in "Grupos Topológicos" by Tkachenko (1997):
Let $G$ a locally compact group and $H\triangleleft G$. If $G/H$ and $H$ are compactly generated, then so is $G$.
We say that $G$ is locally compact if for each $g\in G$ there exists a compact neighbourhood of $g$ in $G$ (i. e., a compact subset of $G$ containing an open subset $V$ for which $g\in V$).
We say that $G$ is compactly generated if there is a compact subset $K$ such that $G=\langle K\rangle$.
A closed and continuous function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is perfect if for every $y\in Y$, $f^{-1}(y):=f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is a compact subspace of $X$.
The proof is:
Let $\pi: G\rightarrow G/H$, given by $\pi(g)=gH$, $\forall g\in G$. Since $G/H$ is compactly generated, there is a compact $K\subset G/H$ such that $G/H=\langle K\rangle$. Let $X=\pi^{-1}(K)$. Because $\pi$ is perfect, we can assume, without loss of generality, that $X$ is compact. If $A\subset H$ is compact and $H=\langle A\rangle$, then $A\cup X$ is a compact subset of $G$ and it generates $G$.
I would appreciate if someone could help me with two main questions I have:

Why $\pi$ is perfect? As far as I know (and the author showed this before) $\pi$ is perfect if and only if $H\triangleleft G$ is compact, but here $H$ is not necessary compact.
Where do we need the assumption that $G$ is locally compact?

Note: If it is necessary, we can assume that $G$ is Hausdorff.
Thank you in advance.
